# Access Redux Store from Redux Form

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I am unable to access the redux state from my redux-form.

I have looked at [How to access the redux store within the redux form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846162/how-to-access-the-redux-store-within-the-redux-form) but none of these solutions work.

```
class PersonalInfo extends Component {


    renderContent() {
        console.log(this.state)
......
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
      state
    };
  }

export default reduxForm({
    form: "AccountOverview",
})(connect(mapStateToProps)(PersonalInfo))
```

when i console.log(this.state) or state it results in null

Comment: If you are looking to get initial values from state, it might be worth reading this: https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/initializefromstate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` will map the redux state to a property of your component, so you will able to access it via `props` property. In fact, as the name suggests, the redux state is mapped to the component `props`.

This should work:

```
console.log(this.props.state)
```

Check sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-simple-example-l8i98?fontsize=14)